# How to handle failed AudioFocus requests in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I am working on an application that has media playing features.

I would like to honor `AudioFocus`. I first request `AudiFocus`:

```
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(new CustomOnAudioFocusChangeListener(), AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

This call returns either `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED` or `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED`.
I guess I shouldn't start playback if I receive `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED`. But then  what to do?

Will my `CustomOnAudioFocusChangeListener` be notified when focus becomes available or is it only when you got `AUTOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED` that it starts getting updates?

Should I inform the user and ask him to try again later? Or retry programmatically after some time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What to do depends on how you want your app to react.  You shouldn't start playing, you may want to message your user.  Or if its something non-critical, you may silently ignore the failure and move on.

I believe you only get updates on the listener on success.  You get the updates then so if you're lowered you can choose to duck your output or pause until you regain.

Comment: I'm trying to acquire `AudioFocus` to play a Soundcloud track, upon user request. Ignoring it is simply not possible as it would be perceived as a bug. Notifying the user seems to be the only thing to do unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, notification sounds like the right idea then.  Luckily this should be a rare occurrence.  The only reason you won't get audio focus is if something else is actively using it, in which case the user probably isn't using going to use your app.

Comment: I just checked the Apollo (CyanogenMod default music player) source code and it does nothing on `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED`. I think I'll display a Toast. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @nstCactus They don't do nothing, right! but they also does not start the execution of the audio. They simple return from the play() method when the audio focus request failed.

Comment: From a user perspective, this means nothing happens when you press play.: no retries, no notification of any kind.